# prevent postback of HtmlButton in C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am creating HtmlButton dynamically in .cs file.
Adding it to Panel using

```
HtmlButton b1 = new HtmlButton();
b1.Attribute.Add("onclick","javascript:validateNclick(this.id);");
pnl.Controls.Add(b1); //pnl is Server-side <Asp:Panel>
```

Now how could i prevent postback of it? **I had written javascript which is working in IE(No postback) but not in Mozilla Firefox (go to server-side code directly).**
please help out.

Comment: please provide c# code,i.e. b1.Attribute.Add(... which will work specifically in Firefox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

return false to prevent postback:

```
b1.Attribute.Add("onclick","javascript:validateNclick(this.id);return false;");
```

**Update**:
You can also do this:

```
b1.Attribute.Add("onclick","javascript:return validateNclick(this.id);");
```

Then in your `validateNclick` function, if you want to have postback, return `true`, if not, return `false`.

Comment: but after validation, i could able to return from Javascript depending on condition(if..else)

Comment: i had debugger in Javascript function. When i debug with Firefox,it doesn't go javascript,diectly comes to .cs code. When i will write 'return false;',it will not go to server-side at ll

Answer (score 1):

if you use jQuery you can use `preventDefault()` to do this

Comment: you can't prevent post back directly using c#.javascript should prevent that.if you usning jQuery it is cross platform

Comment: See this [http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and [http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-snippet-the-epreventdefault-function](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/jquery-snippet-the-epreventdefault-function)

Answer (score 0):

on the javascript function return true or false and then add the return to your onclick as I  show here.

```
    function validateNclick(me)
    {
       if(allIsOk)
       {
         return true;
       }
       else
       {
         return false
        }
    }
```

and your attribute.

```
b1.Attribute.Add("onclick","javascript:return validateNclick(this);");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b1.Attribute.Add("onclick","return validateNclick(this.id);");

function validateNclick(id){
//...
if(condition){
   return true
}
else{
  return false;
}
}
```